# Indesign: printing booklets with creep

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe-indesign

Currently when I try to print any booklets from InDesign CS5, using Adobe PDF printer, it ignores any bleed settings and just places a white bar in the center of the resulting print, instead of filling it with bleed from both pages.

I think I've checked all settings are were unable to determine how this can be fixed. All my pages have 3mm bleed set up in document settings, and when printing I also checked that the bleed settings are used.

Yet with creep specifically they are ignored for some reason. There is bleed on the sides of the print, but not in the center where creep is supposed to be, it is just filled with white space.

Answer (score 1):

If you want bleed in the gutter, you need to disable (uncheck) "Allow Pages to Shuffle," and break apart the spreads. The shuffle option can be found in the page palette options.

You would then drag each right-hand page rightwards and the page will break. They are still left/right as in spreads, but the spread-pairs are separated vertically:

[image]

You can then have set bleed on the gutter, rather than the bleed being the facing page. Try this on a sampling from your booklet setup and see if it resolves your issue.

You can break individual spreads or the whole document in this manner.

Comment: I am not even going to test this as this solution is completely infeasible. I am not going to be sitting around manually dragging pages, risking mixing up the order if there are no numbers present, this is stupid. What If I have a 100 pages?

Comment: This is not a "test solution" it is **the** solution. You cannot add a bleed to the gutter in InDesign without shuffling. You have to shuffle a 100 page document because you set up the document wrong, and you only need to shuffle spreads that have a gutter bleed. When you make a new document properly, then there is no juggling, you just do it correctly. Worrying about risking a minor mistake when working is just an irrational fear. You'll get over it.

Comment: "You have to shuffle a 100 page document because you set up the document wrong" But how do I set it up right then so I don't have to shuffle, how to correctly set up the new document for this? For me it would be much faster to make a new empty document correctly and insert pages into it than shuffle 100 pages.